# Generate John the Ripper rule

Tags: password-cracking, john-the-ripper

[This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32508/pointers-for-john-the-ripper-rulesets) asks for pointers about generating JtR rulesets, but the OP states

> I understand how to use it to make various permutations from a given wordlist

Could someone please explain that? From [the documentation](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/doc/MODES), it seems as though REGEX mode, MASK mode, and Wordlist mode all permit this.

But how to generate a rule that contains permutations of a certain word (suffixes, prefixes, 1337speak)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution for suffixes and prefixes for a given fixed, without 1337speak.

Using [MASK mode](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/doc/MASK), you give parameters on the command line. If the known word part is `barquux` and you need to suffix 3 characters and prefix 2, all of them digits, use

```
john -mask=?d?dbarquux?d?d?d -min-len=9 -max-len=14 file_to_crack
```

For mask options, see the [MASK mode documentation](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/doc/MASK) file.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like John the Ripper (JtR) to have permutations of certain words from a wordlist (let them be in the file dict.txt) with 1-printable-ASCII-character suffix, 1-printable-ASCII-character prefix, 1337speak, with the MASK attack and Hybrid Mask, you could use commands like this:

```
john.exe --wordlist=dict.txt --rules=All --mask=?w?a hash.txt
john.exe --wordlist=dict.txt --rules=All --mask=?a?w hash.txt
```

The 3l33t rules are included in the rules of the above commands.